# Calling function through Apply vs direct calling from Currying functions

Tags: javascript, scope, currying

I'm trying to implement currying function:

```
function sum(a, b, c) {
console.log('SUM'+JSON.stringify(arguments))
  return a + b + c;
}

var curry= function (func,...n) {
      return function(...args2) {
         //console.log('arg2s'+args2)
        return func.apply(this,n.concat(args2));


  };

}

curry(sum,1,2)(3) //SUM{"0":1,"1":2,"2":3}, O/P:6
```

Above gives correct output, but i am not getting the necessity to use apply.

So, if i change my function to below:

```
var curry= function (func,...n) {
      return function(...args2) {
         //console.log('arg2s'+args2)
        return func(n.concat(args2));


  };

}
curry(sum,1,2)(3) //SUM{"0":[1,2,3]}  O/P:"1,2,3undefinedundefined"
```

I basically have two questions here:

1. Why is the implementation of curry not working when calling func directly?Why is the output such weird ?

2.How do i change my function in a way that i can call it as below and should return sum:
curry(1)(2)(3)/curry(1,2)(3)/curry(1,2,3) etc instead of the way i'm calling currently.
I could find some solutions on the web, but couldn't understand .

ex:

```
function curry(func) {

  return function curriedFunc(...args) {
    if (args.length >= func.length) {
      return func.apply(this, args);
    } else {
      return function(...args1) {
        return curriedFunc.apply(this, args.concat(args1));
      }
    }
  };

}
```

Any help would be highly appreciated !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `func` accepts three arguments: `a`, `b`, and `c`. When you do:

```
return func(n.concat(args2));
```

you're passing it *one* argument, an array. It's equivalent to:

```
const arr = n.concat(args2);
return func(arr);
```

Sounds like you'd want to *spread* the arguments into the call of `func` instead:

```
return func(...n, ...args2)
```

With spread syntax, each item from the iterable is put into a parameter. Eg, if the `n` array has one item, it gets set as the first argument passed to `func`, and if `args2` has 2 items, the first gets set as the second argument passed, and the second gets set as the third argument passed.

```js
function sum(a, b, c) {
  console.log('SUM' + JSON.stringify(arguments))
  return a + b + c;
}

var curry = function(func, ...n) {
  return function(...args2) {
    return func(...n, ...args2);
  };

}
curry(sum, 1, 2)(3);
```

> How do i change my function in a way that i can call it as below and should return sum: curry(1)(2)(3)/curry(1,2)(3)/curry(1,2,3) etc

Keep track of the total number of arguments passed in a closure created the *first* time the function is called. In the returned function, push all arguments to the array, and if the array's length is 3, return the sum, otherwise return the function again:

```js
function sum(a, b, c) {
  return a + b + c;
}

var curry = function(func, ...argsSoFar) {
  const neededArgs = func.length;
  const returnedFn = (...args) => {
    argsSoFar.push(...args);
    if (argsSoFar.length === neededArgs) {
      return func(...argsSoFar);
    } else {
      return returnedFn;
    }
  };
  return returnedFn;
}
console.log(
  curry(sum, 1, 2)(3),
  curry(sum)(1, 2)(3),
  curry(sum)(1)(2, 3),
  curry(sum)(1)(2)(3),
);
```

Comment: How was return func.apply(this,n.concat(args2)); taking care of it? Only difference is use of apply here.. how was apply handling the arguments ?(Problem 1)

Comment: `apply` takes an array (2nd parameter) and calls the function with each item of the array as an argument. If `this` isn't an issue, `fn.apply(null, args)` is exactly equivalent to `fn(...args)`. Your original code was doing the equivalent of `fn(args)`.

Comment: Thank u soooooo much... i missed this(apply takes array and passes argument one after the other from array).Also, the explanation for  use of spread operator  makes sense.Thanks

Comment: I thought of checking Solution for Problem 2 and then marking resolved.. sorry.. accepted it :)